# Localising Installer

Tags: windows-installer

How to localise a MSI dynamically. Means the installer should read the OS language being used and it should by itself run in that language. How ca we do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put the decision in the hands of the user. But....there is an "undocumented and untested" way of doing it (with the caveat I have never tried this myself):

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/